# How to redirect to specific page after installing the app in facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

After adding a tab to the page (i.e http://www.facebook.com/add.php), how to redirect to specific location?

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following:

```
<html>
<?php
header('Location: http://the page you want to redirect the user to/');
?>
```